# How to format existing date using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to format date time using JavaScript/jQuery but it's not happening. My code is below.

```
<div id="divID"></div>
    <script>
      var formatDate = function(date){
          return date.getDate() + "/" + date.getMonth() + "/" +date.getYear() + " "+  date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getMintutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();
      }
      var timestamp="2016-12-16 07:58:30 AM ";
      var date= new Date(timestamp);
      document.getElementById('divID').innerHTML = formatDate(date);
    </script>
```

Here I have the existing time `2016-12-16 07:58:30 AM` and I need change it to `16-12-2016 07:58:30 AM` but here I could not get the proper output.

Comment: Check this plugin https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat

Comment: You can use `moment.js` http://momentjs.com/ It's very easy.

Answer (score 5):

Your code has a few issues:

- You have a syntax error, you're calling `getMintutes()`
- You appear to be attempting to show the minutes twice, so you can remove one of those calls
- `getFullYear()` fits your needs better than `getYear()`
- You should use `-` not `/` to delimit the date values.
- You can add `AM` or `PM` to the end of the string by checking if `hours < 12`
- Your timestamp string isn't valid. It should not contain 'AM' or 'PM' - hence why the code doesn't work in Firefox.

With that in mind, try this:

```js
var formatDate = function(date) {
  return date.getDate() + "-" + date.getMonth() + "-" + date.getFullYear() + " " +  ('0' + date.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0' + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0' + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2) + ' ' + (date.getHours() < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM');
}

var timestamp = "2016-12-16 07:58:30";
var date = new Date(timestamp);
document.getElementById('divID').innerHTML = formatDate(date);
```

```html
<div id="divID"></div>
```

You could use a library to make the date formatting logic simpler, but it's rather wasteful to load an entirely library when a single line of code works fine.

Comment: also timestamp should be `"2016-12-16 07:58:30"`  without "AM"

Comment: sorry here `AM/PM` is missing.

Comment: Also i need `AM/PM`.

Comment: @satya added that for you

Comment: Check this in all browser. Its working chrome fine bur firefox not working.

Comment: That's because the timestamp you're using isn't technically valid. Remove the `AM`/`PM` from the end of it and it works fine. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Then how to add AM/PM any other method ?

Comment: I'm saying the *input* should not contain the AM/PM - the *output* value will still show it. You can see the same in the other answers suggesting using MomentJS - they've all removed the AM/PM.

Answer (score 2):

The timestamp you are using will return an invalid date so you should remove the `AM`. Using **[moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)** you can do it like this:

```js
var timestamp = "2016-12-16 07:58:30";
var formattedDate = moment(timestamp).format('DD-MM-YYYY h:mm:ss A');
console.log(formattedDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @satya, have you remove `AM` from the `timestamp`? Because the code from the answer works. Hit the `Run code snippet` button to see it in action. Also, on Firefox too.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a library named `moment.js` http://momentjs.com/

```
var date = new Date();
moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss A')
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery dateFormat](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat) is a separate plugin. You need to load that explicitly using a `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery UI Datepicker for getting the formatted date like the following.

```
let myDate = '2020-11-10';
$.datepicker.formatDate('dd-M-yy', new Date(myDate));
```

The above code will return 10-Nov-2020.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired output using JQuery UI Datepicker Widget as shown below.

```
var timestamp="2016-12-16 07:58:30 AM ";
var desiredTimestamp = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', new Date(timestamp.split(' ')[0])) + ' ' + timestamp.split(' ')[1] + ' ' + timestamp.split(' ')[2];
```